# Retrieve entries by random sort, then resort alphabetically

Tags: entries, random, plugin-supersort, sort

I need to pull X entries with

```
{% set randEntries = craft.entries.section('presenters').order('RAND()').limit(10) %}
```

But then sort them alphabetically on entry.lastName.

Do I need to [Supersort](https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/SuperSort) for this, and if so, how do I apply it? Do I need to pull the entries first, and then run the sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recon Supersort is they way to go, as its got some really handy functions to make this sort of thing a breeze. Try with the following:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('presenters').order('RAND()').limit(10) %}
{% set sortedEntries = entries | supersort('sortAs', '{lastName}') %}

{% for item in sortedEntries %}
    {{ item.title }}
{% endfor %}
```